# How to use page number instead of \thefigure for figures

Tags: floats, numbering

I would like to try a little experiment. I'd like to number figures in a document with the number of the page it is on. When the text refers to "Fig 34.2", it means look at the second figure on page 34. Can you suggest how I can achieve this?

Now, I know that page numbering is done at the output stage, so I believe I cannot straightforwardly redefine the figure-related macros. I even suspect it may have to be done in two passes.

Thank you much.

Comment: The page number is easy using \pageref.  The tricky part is keeping track of how many figures wind up on each page.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% \usepackage{bophook} % Bophook is apparently old? But it works I guess
%     \AtBeginPage{%
%         \setcounter{figure}{0}
%     }

\AddToHook {shipout/background}{\setcounter{figure}{0}} %% Happens at the start of every page

\usepackage{subcaption}
    \DeclareCaptionFormat{page}
    {%
        \textbf{Figure \thepage.\thefigure #2}#3
    }
    \captionsetup{format=page}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\newpage

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blue.png}
  \caption{A picture of the universe!}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for! (Blue is just a picture of a *"green box"*)

[image]

Comment: setting the figure counter at the start of a page is not enough a figure saved on page 2 but floatig and appearing as the second figure on page 10 needs to set the caption, o page 2, to 10.3

Comment: @DavidCarlisle didn't think of that...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `\figurelabel` after each `\caption`.  If formats the figure numbers for every figure at `\begin{document}` and stores them using global macros.  In the first pass `\thefigure` will default to `\arabic{figure}`. (Do not mess with the figure counter!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newcounter{figuresperpage}
\newcommand{\figurepage}{0}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figurelabel}{{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newfigure{\arabic{figure}}{\thepage}}%
\@esphack}}

\newcommand{\newfigure}[2]{% #1 = \arabic{figure}, #2 = \thepage
  \ifnum\figurepage=#2\relax
    \stepcounter{figuresperpage}%
  \else
    \xdef\figurepage{#2}%
    \setcounter{figuresperpage}{1}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\xdef\csname figure#1\endcsname{#2.\thefiguresperpage}% store formatte figure number
}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@ifundefined{figure\arabic{figure}}{\arabic{figure}}%
  {\csname figure\arabic{figure}\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\section{test}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{first}\figurelabel
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{second}\figurelabel
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-12]   
\end{document}
```